# django saving messages to database via node server and socket.io

Tags: python, django, node.js, redis, socket.io

I have node server:

```
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer().listen(4000);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
var cookie_reader = require('cookie');
var querystring = require('querystring');

var redis = require('redis');
var sub = redis.createClient();

//Subscribe to the Redis chat channel
sub.subscribe('chat');

//Configure socket.io to store cookie set by Django
io.use(function(){
    io.set('authorization', function(data, accept){
        if(data.headers.cookie){
            data.cookie = cookie_reader.parse(data.headers.cookie);
           return accept(null, true);
        }
        return accept('error', false);
     });
    io.set('log level', 1);
 });

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

//Grab message from Redis and send to client
sub.on('message', function(channel, message){
    socket.send(message);
});

//Client is sending message through socket.io
socket.on('send_message', function (message) {
    values = querystring.stringify({
        comment: message,
        sessionid: socket.handshake.cookie['sessionid'],
    });

    var options = {
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 8000,
        path: '/node_api',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Content-Length': values.length
        }
    };

    //Send message to Django server
    var req = http.request(options, function(res){
        res.setEncoding('utf8');

        //Print out error message
        res.on('data', function(message){
            if(message != 'Everything worked :)'){
                console.log('Message: ' + message);
            }
        });
    });

    req.write(values);
    req.end();
});
```

});

When I send message it does not save in the database..

Here is my view for django:

```
@csrf_exempt
def node_api(request):
    print "inside node"
    try:
        print "inside try"
        session = Session.objects.get(session_key=request.POST.get("sessionid"))
        print "first"
        user_id = session.get_decode().get("_auth_user_id")
        print user_id
        user = User.objects.get(id=user_id)

        Comments.objects.create(user=user, text=request.POST.get("comment"))
        r = redis.StrictRedis(host="localhost", port=6379, db=0)
        r.publish("chat", user.username + ": " + request.POST.get("comment"))

        return HttpResponse("Everything worked :")
    except Exception, e:

        return HttpResponseServerError(str(e))
```

Whats wrong in here??

Can anyone guide me to right direction?
When I go to '/node_api/' url it says Session matching query doesnot exist..

My view for displaying message:

```
@login_required
def home(request):
    print "entered"
    comments = Comments.objects.select_related().all()[0:100]
    return render(request, "index.html", locals())
```

When I submit the message its not saving to database neither displaying...

Thanx in advance??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using python then why don't you try python way of doing realtime.

Try tornado with django. It supports socket.io..

You can code in python with no difficulty.
It doesn't mean javascript is not good but try do in python and have a look at tornado, redis, django. YOu will find your solution.